# The moderator firmament is a little less shiny

Tags: discussion, moderators

Because I'm turning in my diamond soon.

Lately the spark of motivation hasn't been there for me, so I'm leaving the job to the rest of the team. I feel very comfortable doing so, they've got more than what it takes to keep the place tidy without me.

It's been fun, I'll see you around.

Comment: Sad to see you go. Although we sometimes disagreed I liked you as a moderator. Thank you for your service and all the best for whatever you do now. :)

Comment: I'll echo dly's sentiment. I didn't always agree with your position, or even your actions, but in spite of that, I think you were exemplary in your service. I remember feeling some apprehension around your election, but you've done a phenomenal job in changing my mind. Thanks for all the hard work you've put into the position.

Comment: @Schism Thank you for the kind words. That means a lot to me.

Answer (score 15):

It's been an honour moderating alongside you Wrigglenite!

Thank you for all the effort you've put in over the years, you've always gone above and beyond what is expected for mods. Your passion for the site and community is obvious, and we're all the better for having it.

I wish you all the best for the future, and hope to see you around soon :)

Comment: Likewise, I was impressed by your contributions on meta since before you were elected, but what I really loved were your high quality memes after I got my own diamond.

Answer (score 15):

The moderator team will have a little less shine, but you can bow out proudly.

Nobody asked you to take the job, and you did it for 2 years. And smashing everybody else in terms of flags sorted.

We will see you around! You may lose the diamond, but I'll always enjoy your presence.

Answer (score 14):

You'll be sorely missed! You've always been the strongest advocate for quality on the moderator team, and things just won't be the same without your input.

Best of luck in the future, and don't be a stranger!

Comment: Thank you Wipqozn, you've never failed to chime in with calm, reasonable discussion to whatever problems the moderator team was facing. You've helped us all a lot and I know you'll continue to do so.

Answer (score 12):

Though I haven't served along side you for very long, I do know you have been a moderator/member of the site for a while who truly wanted what was in the community's best interest. I still remember when you went from "DanmakuGrazer" to "Wrigglenite" and I had to stop for a second to figure out who this was...

All the best, and I'm sure we will still see you around, so this won't be a *goodbye* but more of a *see you later*!

Comment: One name is more of a username, the other is more of a personal name. I thought I wanted to be a username kind of person here, but then realised I wanted to use a name. If that makes sense.